# adal4j: testAcquireToken fails

Tags: java, azure-active-directory

I've downloaded [adal4j from Github](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java) and I've built it with maven. Compilation passed successfully but one of the tests - [`testAcquireToken()`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal4j/AuthenticationContextTest.java#L102) always fails with the same error:

> AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.

What I am doing wrong? I am interesting exactly in the scenario of this test.

My environment: Windows 7 64 bit. Java version "1.7.0_02" 32 bit.

**testAcquireToken**

```
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AssertionError: 
      Unexpected method call AuthenticationCallback.onFailure(com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: 285b162f-2655-429a-bde7-3c5042aed74e\r\nCorrelation ID: b5eae0c9-2574-4ffb-ade8-8a25f02df980\r\nTimestamp: 2014-09-09 13:48:26Z"}):
        AuthenticationCallback.onSuccess(<any>): expected: 1, actual: 0
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContextTest.testAcquireToken(AuthenticationContextTest.java:102)
    Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: 
      Unexpected method call AuthenticationCallback.onFailure(com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: 285b162f-2655-429a-bde7-3c5042aed74e\r\nCorrelation ID: b5eae0c9-2574-4ffb-ade8-8a25f02df980\r\nTimestamp: 2014-09-09 13:48:26Z"}):
        AuthenticationCallback.onSuccess(<any>): expected: 1, actual: 0
        at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
        at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
        at $Proxy15.onFailure(Unknown Source)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:133)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:112)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    ... Removed 30 stack frames
```

Comment: It is entirely possible the client secret has simply expired and the test wasn't updated. Have you tried running this yourself?

Comment: where can I get updated secret?

Comment: You cannot get the secret for the test tenant without admin access. You can update the test to run against your own test tenant, to which you *do* have admin access. The process to get the secret would be the process to add an application.

Comment: In practice, you need to have paid subscription for Windows Azure, login to https://portal.azure.com/ and select 'Active Directory' (good luck finding it - Microsoft is currently in the middle of some kind of Azure upgrade where Active Directory component is randomly MIA, try also https://manage.windowsazure.com), select "Applications", select "Add" (currently in the footer). This gives you a new Client ID and allows creating client keys.

Comment: Another option would be https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/app-registration